# iMovie picture in picture resizing

Tags: macos, imovie

I am placing multiple video picture in pictures in my iMovie project. Is there a function with which, once I find a size I like for the first one or two, I can then apply that same universal size to every picture in picture in the project?

I'm trying to avoid having to do all 40 odd clips manually and I want to be sure each is the same size, rather than just guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Use the paste adjustments tool. Here is a quick video on how to use it. You're right, it will save you A LOT of time. http://youtu.be/kYWsFwBLNHY

Comment: The video is not available.